# Creating Nested List using PDFBox in Java

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am working on PDFBox API. I am creating a PDF which contains many things like Graph, Table, Header, Footer, Text in form of List. There may be any 4 graphs one table, orientation can be any. All are specified in an imaginary rectangle so that all this fits on PDF page perfectly.

So as mentioned Now I have a problem how to create List of Text (which is in Form of List). This

1. I am a good Web Developer.
2. I am doing B.Tech. from private college and
   currently doing an internship.
3. My skills

   a. Java

   b. Python

It should be displayed in this form only.

I think all data should be stored in ArrayList it's simple but as we see point 3 it is nested list. How to store this kind of data.

Guide Me

Comment: Declares the ArrayList for My Skills

Comment: Is your question about displaying or about data structures?